# 12.04 the application compiz has shut down unexpectidly

Tags: 12.04

I ran updates about a month or more ago, and when it was taking a long time I tried to stop it, but it ended up completing the updates. When I restarted the computer I got the error "the application compiz has shut down unexpectedly" and nothing shows up on my desktop. The second user seems to be working well and this is how I got online to ask this question.

Comment: 12.04 is three months away from EOL (April 2017), so you may want to move to a newer release and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there could have been issues with the connection.

I suggest running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as it will attempt to fix any issues from the upgrade command. Especially if it was acting real slow during the initial update.

If it still doesn't resolve it, try attempting `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`